# Is there record number limit in LevelDB?

Tags: leveldb, database, nosql

Is there maximum key number limit in LevelDB or key number limit for productivity (like in Kyoto Cabinet: the number of records determines number of buckets that must be calculated before database is created; if number of records override that limit db loses productivity, but keep working)?

Answer (score 2):

No limit that I would know about. However if database gets very large then most of the data is stored in the last level (about 89%) and merging with it may become expensive (a lot of files in the last level will overlap with to be merged data in the previous level).

Another thing that say at 40Gb you'll have 20480 2Mb files in one folder and it could be that your file system's performance will degrade with so many files.

To know for sure you need to experiment.